# 52 week price range for USDC

Tags: cryptocurrency, quotes

I am looking at the [52 week price range for USD Coin](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/USDC-USD/) and it shows

```
52 Week Range:  0.9874 - 2.3496
```

Since it is pegged 1:1 to USD, how did it go all the way to $2.3496?

Comment: It most likely didn't.

Comment: @HartCO could Yahoo Finance be wrong?

Comment: I don't see any points on the chart above 1.04xx so it seems like it's wrong.

Comment: It doesn't appear as a value on any day in the historical data so it seems to be an error. That said there's no inherent reason a peg can't break.